# Using category slug in url rather than pk

Tags: python, django

Right now I am able to show a product detail page by going to `example.com/products/1` However I would like to be able to go `example.com/<category_slug>/<product_slug>`

**views.py**

```
def product_detail(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'main/product_detail.html', {'product': product})
```

**root urls.py**

```
from main.views import product_detail

path('products/<int:pk>/', product_detail, name='product-detail'),
```

Comment: Post your 'Product' models

Answer (score 1):

In your `Product` model you would need something like this:

```
class Product(model.Models):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # Other fields
```

Then in your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
def product_detail(request, slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    return render(request, 'main/product_detail.html', {'product': product})
```

In your `urls.py` file:

```
from main.views import product_detail

path('products/<str:slug>/', product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

It's the exact same as using a PK, you just use a string instead. The string just has to be stored in the database (it kind of acts like a "primary key" in that sense). It may also make sense to make it a unique field. Notice that I wrapped the `.get()` method in a `try` and `except`. This will be very useful for people typing random things into their request.

EDIT: Technically, you should also add the flag `unique=True` to your slug field. This will prevent `.get()` from breaking.